# EditText input background in Android

Tags: android, background, android-edittext

I use `EditText` like this :

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="input something"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#04ff00"
            android:textColorHint="#0094fd"
            android:textColorHighlight="#ffea00"/>
```

**This is result :**
[image]

Like image, I want to change background of text when input, not highlight.

How to do it ?

Comment: What wrong with highlight...

Comment: i can't change background of text when input with highlight. when double tap on string, it will show color highlight, but in here, i want to change color background when input. you can see it in image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this I do it for you.....

```
        final EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mEditText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //Lock the listener
            mEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

            String  textString = s.toString(); 

            if(textString.length()>0){
                Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(textString);
                spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, textString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                mEditText.setText(spanText);
                mEditText.setSelection(textString.length());
            }

            //Give back the listener
            mEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }
    });
```